# Jackson fails deserialization when attributes are included

Tags: java, xml, jackson

This is sort of a follow up to 
[Jackson deserialize to list of child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278899/jackson-deserialize-to-list-of-child-elements)

```
<Trade>
  <row>
    <TradeID>1</TradeID>
  </row>
  <row>
    <TradeID>2</TradeID>
  </row>
</Trade>
```

```
public class Trade {
  List<Row> rows;
  public class Row {
    int tradeID;
  }
}
```

And I can deserialize my Row objects with

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
List<Row> rows = Arrays.asList(xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Row[].class));
```

But if I have attributes in the Trade object such that it looks like the following, it fails to parse (I get a list of objects that have null values for everything).

Can I tell Jackson to just forget about the attributes? (Unfortunately I have 0 control over the system generating all this noise)

```
<Trade delimiter="~" header="true" date="2019-05-30 13:30:42" fileName="CRD.VANGFI_BOD.Trade.0000000007" sequence="7" ALLOC_AGGR_SAME_NULL_FIELDS="ACCT_CD,ACCT_NAME,TRADE_ID,PSET" ALLOC_AGGR_SUM_FIELDS="FEE_1_AMT,FEE_2_AMT,FEE_3_AMT,FEE_4_AMT,FEE_5_AMT,FEE_6_AMT,EXEC_QTY,EXEC_AMT,INC_AMT,INC_BASE_AMT,EXEC_ORIGINAL_FACE,NET_PRIN_AMT,NET_PRIN_BASE_AMT" OUTPUT_TYPE="xml" ALLOC_AGGR_AGGREGATION_FIELDS="ORDER_ID,UMA_HOLDING_ACCT_CD" ENABLE_ALLOCATION_AGGREGATION="N">
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization

Comment: Have you tried this `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on the `Trade` class?

Comment: I was trying to do this without creating a Trade class

Answer (score 0):

Did you try configuring this.

```
xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

Comment: I did unfortunately.